# Can I get the multitouch touchpad to respond to a double tap for right click

Tags: dell-latitude

the Dell Latitude E6410 I just got for work has some of the multi-touch features you see on a Mac book/pro

now with only some of the multitouch gestures I find myself naturally using the other half (so I can two finger scroll and pinch etc)

The one that I'm missing is the two finger tap for right click.  Does anyone know if this can be enabled or if it is possible to hack a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

If it has multitouch you may want to look at this

http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/484463-synaptics-multi-touch-double-tap.html

It is saying that you should

- Enable two finger scroll in synaptics
  driver
- Disable scrolling type in the
  scrolling section of twofingerscroll 
  program
- Under tapping section,    select "one
  one finger" as right    button.